# DynamoDB Table Missing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I had created a simple table in dynamo called userId, I could view it in the AWS console and query it through some java on my local machine. This morning, however, I could no longer see the table in the dynamo dashboard but I could still query it through the java. The dashboard showed no tables at all (I only had one, the missing 'userId'). I then just created a new table using the dashboard, called it userId and populated it. However, now when I run my java to query it, the code is returning the items from the missing 'userId' table, not this new one! Any ideas what is going on?

Ok, that's strange. I thought dynamo tables were not specified by region but I noticed once I created this new version of 'userId' it was viewable under the eu-west region but then I could see the different (previously missing!) 'userId' table in the us-east region. They both had the same table name but contained different items. I didn't think this was possible?

Comment: DynamoDB tables are tied to the region in which they are created and are not required to be unique across regions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the services of Amazon Web Services are in a single region. The only exceptions are Route 53 (DNS), IAM, and CloudFront (CDN). The reason is that you want to control the location of your data, mainly for regulatory reasons. Many times your data can't leave the US or Europe or any other region.
It is possible to create high availability for your services within a single region with availability zones. This is how the highly available services as DynamoDB or S3 are giving such functionality, by replicating the data between availability zones, but within a single region.

Comment: Thanks, I just didnt realize the Zone was different